# How to Create a table and name it after a record stored in a class

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to create a table that will use the name of an ID code stored in a class(Named UserInfo in the code). I've also tried storing the data as a string variable, but I keep getting : 'SQL logic error
near "83883": syntax error. My Code:

```
            sqlite_conn.Open();
            sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=RetailSystem.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;");

            string MakeBsketTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + UserInfo.CustomerID + " (BasketItemName VARCHAR(40), IndividualItemQuantity INT, IndividualItemPrice INT, TotalItemQuantity INT, TotalItemCost INT, GrossCost INT)";
            sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = MakeBsketTable;
            sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is the resulting value of `MakeBsketTable`?  Basically, what is the value of `UserInfo.CustomerID`?  The error implies that it's a number, and numeric table names *probably* aren't allowed (and definitely aren't a good idea).  Why are you trying to create a table *per-customer* anyway?  It sounds like the wrong approach for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, you are correct that the CustomerID is a number. Im doing the tables per customer as part of my analysis for a project that would show incorrect or inefficient methods to create an item basket. I've already created a working basket that uses just one table

Comment: Well, in that case a SQL syntax error definitely qualifies as an incorrect or ineffecient method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to create a table with an Id as the name, since it's a table you can have multiple records in it.
You can add the Id primary key field on the table which will be neater

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I don't see the logic in creating a table named as an ID. It is much easier to create several tables with a relationship between them. Read about database normalization.

Secondly, any query in SQL must end with symbol ";".